# MSSQL Rest API запрос

Tags: sql-server, rest

Можно ли средствами MSSQL сделать запрос на урл  который отдаёт таблицу, отобразить её в виде таблицы?

```
declare @xmlhttp int
declare @hr int
declare @text char(8000)
exec sp_OACreate 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP', @xmlhttp out
exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @xmlhttp, 'open', NULL, 'GET', 
      'http://10.0.0.0:8080/API/flat?token=c57aa1', false
if @hr=0  exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @xmlhttp,
  'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/html'
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @xmlhttp, 'send', NULL, null
-- тут hr равен нолю - без ошибок
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @xmlhttp, 
'responseText',  @text out;
--- тут возникают ошибки "конвертации"
```

Проблема возникла когда `responseText` более 8000 символов - то не удаётся его считать (ограничение MSSQL на размер строки). Если другие средства получить json таблицу с другого сервера и обработать в MSSQL?

UPD: И... походу... не получается текст в таблицу преобразовать (ранее писал изврат через xml, через xml работает). Пишу...

```
SELECT 
cast((select value from OPENJSON(value) 
  where [key]='id') as int) id,
cast((select value from OPENJSON(value) 
  where [key]='name') as varchar(32)) name
FROM OPENJSON( (select x from @tab)  )
```

Вроде ок, засовываю в хранимку делаю exec и...

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_rest2, Line 32 [Batch
>   Start Line 2] Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.

JSON вид `[{"id":18120,"name":"Smart"},{"id":18124,"name":"Smart4"}]`

Не сталкивался ли кто с таким приколом? В хранимке не работает, а без хранимки - работает (сервер 2016)

Comment: Какой тип переменной @xmlhttp?

Comment: а `varchar(max)` вместо `varchar(8000)` вы там нигде определить не можете?

Comment: varchar(max) - даёт ошибку 8004271A - сейчас почитаю что это...  не могу найти описание...

Comment: Старая ссылка, но по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259630/how-to-call-webservice-from-tsql-sql-server-2000

Comment: Ну, то есть не использовать OUT-переменную, а кидать результат во временную таблицу и брать оттуда

Comment: аналогичное решение [тут было](http://www.sql.ru/forum/908709/zubodrobitelnaya-zadachka-s-sp-oagetproperty), со временной таблицей/табличной переменной

Comment: спасибо, помогло обе ссылки (временная таблица).

Comment: там еще есть вариант с `SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647` перед скрптом.  и еще возможно определение `@text` как тип `xml`, или кто он там  вас?

Comment: xml конечно же пробовал. Не ест.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге получилось так

```
declare @xmlhttp int
declare @hr int
exec sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @xmlhttp out
EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @xmlhttp, 'open', NULL, 'GET', 'http://API/flat', false
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @xmlhttp, 'send', NULL, null
declare @tab table (x varchar(max))
if @hr=0 insert into @tab exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @xmlhttp, 'responseText';
exec  @hr = sp_OADestroy @xmlhttp;
```

И запрос вида `[{"id":18120,"name":"Smart"},{"id":18124,"name":"Smart4"}]` разпарсить так

```
select * FROM OPENJSON ((select x from @tab))
with  ( id int  '$.id', name varchar(32) '$.name' )
```

OPENJSON действует с сервера 2016, для более ранних версий можно парсить через xml,
но если в 2016+ версиях OPENJSON не работает, нужно выполнить запрос `ALTER DATABASE YourBase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130` под учёткой, с которой не работает.

Вариант через xml (работает в 2005)

```
declare @q xml
set @q= cast(replace(replace( (select x from @tab),'{','<q>'),'}','</q>') as xml)      
select substring(id,1, charindex(',',id)-1) id,  
    substring(name,2, charindex('",',name)-2) name
 from (    select substring(q,charindex('"id":',q)+5,100) id, 
          substring(q,charindex('"name":',q)+7,100) name,  q 
from ( select  T.c.value('.','char(128)') q  from @q.nodes('/q') T(c) ) t)t
```

Ccылки

- JSON http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql
- Строки более 8К http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259630/how-to-call-webservice-from-tsql-sql-server-2000
- WinHttpRequest http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest
- Настройка OLE http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ole-automation-procedures-server-configuration-option